# Derivation of variance of Zhou (1996) volatility estimator

Tags: volatility, time-series, high-frequency, estimation

Does anyone know how to derive the Variance of Bin Zhou's volatility estimator (Theorem 1) in 'High-Frequency Data and Volatility in Foreign-Exchange Rates' (1996)

[Zhou 1996](http://public.econ.duke.edu/~get/browse/courses/201/spr11/DOWNLOADS/MicroStructure/Zhou-JBES-1996.pdf)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.